# ¿Como testear el enviar un JSON mediante Web Service por POST en php?

Tags: php, json, webservice

Resulta que tengo el siguiente metodo donde recibo un JSON  y obtengo los valores de sus items mandando a guardar a los campos de una base de datos

Metodo que recibe JSON

```
    <?php
    require 'meta.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        $retorno = meta::insert(
                $body['titulo'],
                $body['descripcion'],
                $body['fechaLim'],
                $body['categoria'],
                $body['prioridad']);

        if ($retorno) {
            print json_encode(array(
                 'estado'   => '1',
                 'mensaje'  => 'Creacion exitosa'
                ));
        }
        else
        {
            print json_encode(array(
                    'estado'    =>  '2',
                    'mensaje'   =>  'Creación fallida'
                )); 
        }
    }?>
```

en el archivo meta.php, tengo el siguiente metodo insertar para mandar a guardar a la base de datos.

```
public static function insert($titulo,$descripcion,$fechaLim,$categoria,$prioridad)
    {
        $comando = "INSERT INTO meta(".
                   "titulo,".
                   "descripcion,".
                   "fechaLim,".
                   "categoria,".
                   "prioridad)".
                   "VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?)";
        $sentencia = database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($comando);


        return $sentencia->execute(
            array(
                    $titulo,
                    $descripcion,
                    $fechaLim,
                    $categoria,
                    $prioridad
                )
            );
    }
```

Tengo la duda de ¿Como enviar los parámetros por web service para guardar en la base de datos?
estoy utilizando postman para testear pero nose de que forma se debe hacer.

Al realizar la prueba en postman da el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'titulo' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php:67 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php(67): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\obtener_metas.php(59): meta::insert(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php on line 67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seleccionas **POST** como metodo de envío
2. Te vas a **BODY** y seleccionas **form-data** (form data es el equivalente a llenar los campos de una forma que usa Post para el envío).
3. Agregas tus valores en las columnas **Key** y **Value**
4. Presionas **SEND**, como siempre

EDICION:

Para enviar JSON, debes cambiar los pasos 2 y 3:

2. Te vas a **BODY** y seleccionas **raw**, y ahí hay un dropdown, donde seleccionas **JSON(application/json)**
3. Capturas tus datos en formato JSON

`{
        "titulo":"",
        "descripcion":"",
        "fechaLim":"",
        "categoria":"",
        "prioridad":""
     }`

Comment: me da el siguiente error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'titulo' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php:67 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php(67): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\obtener_metas.php(59): meta::insert(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\i_wish\php\meta.php on line 67

Comment: No obtuvo los datos, posiblemente porque no le enviaste JSON. Para enviar JSON, necesitas usar **raw**. Voy a modificar mi respuesta para incluir esta información.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, eso era. No sabia como enviar JSON. otra consulta nada mas por aca como para que me des una guia estos valores los voy a obtener de un formulario en html y debo mandarlos por JSON ¿Como se aria?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587221/send-json-data-with-jquery